# How to fix between that isn't inclusive for date

Tags: sql, between

I want to search for data between given dates. I'm able to get results that are between but it's not including the day at the beginning and end of between statement.

I tried just switching the days that use the between on such as adding or subtracting a day, but there's gotta be another way.

SQL:

```
WHERE "Date" Between '09/02/2019' AND '09/06/2019' 
AND (sf.TemplateName = 'Nassco Lacp') 
AND (sf.ProjectName = 'Crossbore Safety Program') 
AND (sf.WorkOrderNumber LIKE '%2715%I1%')
```

I should get all data between those days including the work done on the the second and sixth, but for some reason I'm not getting stuff done on the sixth. HELP!

Comment: What data type is `"Date"? And which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `between` with dates!  The time component can cause a problem.  Instead:

```
where date >= '2019-09-02' and
      date < '2019-09-07' and    -- note this is one day later
      . . .
```

Most databases understand the YYYY-MM-DD for date constants.

Comment: A `DATE` value does not have a time component (except in Oracle)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I still think this is a best practice, because often just looking at the data, it is not clear whether or not the value is a date or date/time.  You might be interested in what Aaron Bertrand has to say about the subject with regards to SQL Server:  https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.

Comment: I know that blog post. And while it's true for timestamp  (or Oracle's DATE) values, it's simply not true for (real) date values.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this happends when the `Date` field is a timestamp data type. What happends is that a specific date such as `09/02/2019` it's interpreted as `09/02/2019 00:00:00` so any value before is exclured.

Try **(ORACLE DBMS)**:

```
WHERE Trunc("Date") Between '09/02/2019' AND '09/06/2019'
```

Try **(SQL Server)**:

```
WHERE cast("Date" As Date) Between '09/02/2019' AND '09/06/2019'
```

Comment: Use of `trunc("Date")` turns off index range scans in the case `"Date"` is indexed